# How to swipe top down JQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to make event on swiping up and down  instead of left and right

i have this roll as image shows:
[image: how to make swipe top down]

I can handle the event using arrow icon (onClick()) but i want to add swipe up down event,
when adding swipe event it works on left right
I want it up down as image displays
any help?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

jQuery Mobile natively provides us with the ability to capture the swipeleft and swiperight. It does not however offer us swipeup and swipedown out of the box. Adapting what the jQuery team has done for swipeleft and swiperight, we are able to create and capture those events in the same manner. See the following code to implement swipeup and swipedown:

```
(function() {
    var supportTouch = $.support.touch,
            scrollEvent = "touchmove scroll",
            touchStartEvent = supportTouch ? "touchstart" : "mousedown",
            touchStopEvent = supportTouch ? "touchend" : "mouseup",
            touchMoveEvent = supportTouch ? "touchmove" : "mousemove";
    $.event.special.swipeupdown = {
        setup: function() {
            var thisObject = this;
            var $this = $(thisObject);
            $this.bind(touchStartEvent, function(event) {
                var data = event.originalEvent.touches ?
                        event.originalEvent.touches[ 0 ] :
                        event,
                        start = {
                            time: (new Date).getTime(),
                            coords: [ data.pageX, data.pageY ],
                            origin: $(event.target)
                        },
                        stop;

                function moveHandler(event) {
                    if (!start) {
                        return;
                    }
                    var data = event.originalEvent.touches ?
                            event.originalEvent.touches[ 0 ] :
                            event;
                    stop = {
                        time: (new Date).getTime(),
                        coords: [ data.pageX, data.pageY ]
                    };

                    // prevent scrolling
                    if (Math.abs(start.coords[1] - stop.coords[1]) > 10) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
                $this
                        .bind(touchMoveEvent, moveHandler)
                        .one(touchStopEvent, function(event) {
                    $this.unbind(touchMoveEvent, moveHandler);
                    if (start && stop) {
                        if (stop.time - start.time < 1000 &&
                                Math.abs(start.coords[1] - stop.coords[1]) > 30 &&
                                Math.abs(start.coords[0] - stop.coords[0]) < 75) {
                            start.origin
                                    .trigger("swipeupdown")
                                    .trigger(start.coords[1] > stop.coords[1] ? "swipeup" : "swipedown");
                        }
                    }
                    start = stop = undefined;
                });
            });
        }
    };
    $.each({
        swipedown: "swipeupdown",
        swipeup: "swipeupdown"
    }, function(event, sourceEvent){
        $.event.special[event] = {
            setup: function(){
                $(this).bind(sourceEvent, $.noop);
            }
        };
    });

})();
```

and here is the answer from [Blackdynamo](http://developingwithstyle.blogspot.com/2010/11/jquery-mobile-swipe-up-down-left-right.html)

Comment: How do I set up listener for swipeupdown event and perform different tasks for swipeup and swipedown event?

Comment: @SantoshGhimire, you can use `$('mySelector').on('swipeup', function() {});` and `$('mySelector').on('swipedown', function() {});`

Comment: I used this jQuery plugin and its the easiest.
https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin

Comment: This answer does not work, if start and target of the swipe is not the same div: See Answer below for fix! fiddle: jsfiddle.net/Q3d9H/124

Comment: I just wanted to add. The answer still works perfect.I added this script to the head, and used "$('.myClassSelector').on('swipedown', function() {});". Worked on the first try. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I had Problems with the accepted answer here, because swiping wasn't detected when origin and target of the swipe were not the same.

Here maybe an easier answer, where i directly override the jquery handleSwipe event (based on jquery.mobile-1.4.5) and append it with a vertical swipe, called up and down:

```
(function( $, window, undefined ) {

    //custom handleSwipe with swiperight, swipeleft, swipeup, swipedown
    $.event.special.swipe.handleSwipe = function( start, stop, thisObject, origTarget ) {
        if ( stop.time - start.time < $.event.special.swipe.durationThreshold ) {
            var horSwipe = Math.abs( start.coords[0] - stop.coords[0] ) > $.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold;
            var verSwipe = Math.abs( start.coords[1] - stop.coords[1] ) > $.event.special.swipe.verticalDistanceThreshold;
            if( horSwipe != verSwipe ) {
                var direction;
                if(horSwipe)
                    direction = start.coords[0] > stop.coords[0] ? "swipeleft" : "swiperight";
                else
                    direction = start.coords[1] > stop.coords[1] ? "swipeup" : "swipedown";
                $.event.trigger($.Event( "swipe", { target: origTarget, swipestart: start, swipestop: stop }), undefined, thisObject);
                $.event.trigger($.Event( direction, { target: origTarget, swipestart: start, swipestop: stop }), undefined, thisObject);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }

    //do binding
    $.each({
        swipeup: "swipe.up",
        swipedown: "swipe.down"
    }, function( event, sourceEvent ) {
        $.event.special[ event ] = {
            setup: function() {
                $( this ).bind( sourceEvent, $.noop );
            },
            teardown: function() {
                $( this ).unbind( sourceEvent );
            }
        };
    }); 
})( jQuery, this );
```

Comment: the "accepted answer worked perfect "
and 50 people voted it up in this community

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808917/how-to-get-swipe-up-and-swipe-down-event-in-jquery-mobile/21644139#21644139

Comment: Try to swipe from bottom div to top div, not working:
http://jsfiddle.net/Q3d9H/124/ My solution can handle that (fiddle is complicated, because i extend the jquery script)

Comment: And before you say, that is the wanted behavior, no it is not. Jquery swipeleft and swiperight also handles different start and target divs correctly. So my new solution is the real correct solution, without any errors. Although the simple example from your link is working fine, it does not handle possible and common usecases.
Best regards