# jQuery Mobile: error panel at bottom

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have seen web-apps which have an "error panel" (for example, semi-transparent yellow panel) which appears at the *bottom* of the screen and then disappears after some seconds.
I would expect that jQuery/jQuery Mobile provides this functionality, but cannot find it in their documentation.
I would be happy to "roll my own", but would prefer to use standard jQuery functionality if possible.
Does anyone have any examples?

Comment: Unfortunately JQM doesn't offer such a widget, although, it would be a great addition.

Comment: I dont know. create your own simple one.

Comment: Use an overlay panel from bottom [How do I use Jquery Mobile Slide Panel to slide up from the bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71019272/10070689)