# HTML5 WebWorks application menu swipedown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, blackberry-webworks

I have this code here for application menu that should be opened when screen is swiped down:

```
<div data-role="panel" id="top" data-dark-modal="true" data-position="top" data-display="push" data-theme="a" class="">
        <div data-role="applicationmenu">
            <a data-role="action" href="#" onclick="sound()">
                <img src="images/on.png" id="test" alt="" />
                <p>Help</p>
            </a>        
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this code is for the swipedown:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function onSwipedown() {
alert("Swipe down event occured.");
}

blackberry.event.addEventListener("swipedown", onSwipedown);

</script>
```

What statement should be used to make the menu work with swipedown function?

Any help would e appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131815/how-to-swipe-top-down-jquery-mobile

Comment: I think this is not the one I'm looking for

Comment: JQM has swipe left and right events only. You either need to do something similar to the answer above, or use another library like hammer js.