# How to get swipe up and swipe down event in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Can you please tell me how to get the "swipe up" and "swipe down" events in jQuery Mobile? I am able to get "swipe right" and "swipe left" event.

Can I use third party library? Can you please give one alert/console in fiddle to get these event?

Comment: can't you use the scroll events ?

Comment: I already see this can you use this on fiddle

Comment: Please use this on fiddle and alert swipe up and down . how to use this plugin

Answer (score 21):

it is the same as my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131815/how-to-swipe-top-down-jquery-mobile)

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3d9H/1/)**

just ill show you how to use swipe up and down events..

```
$('#mydiv').on('swipedown',function(){alert("swipedown..");} );
$('#mydiv').on('swipeup',function(){alert("swipeup..");} );
```

Comment: Which script Library can i add? `<script src="?"></script>`

Comment: jquery-mobile Library

Comment: This is only working in desktops and not in mobile. Comments?

Comment: I've used this even on phone gap, cordova. Works awesome! Ty