# Swipe down to close a lightbox in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, swipe

Is there a mobile framework and/or a simpler alternative to swipe down to close a lightbox, in javascript/jquery for a mobile browser, which could work in a similar fashion that Facebook does?

[image: Facebook swipe down to close]

Comment: consider using jQuery and jQuery Mobile, https://jquery.com/ and https://api.jquerymobile.com/swipe/ (jquery mobile swipe method)

Comment: jQuery Mobile seem to recognize only left-right swipe

Comment: look at this: (fiddle in the question/answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808917/how-to-get-swipe-up-and-swipe-down-event-in-jquery-mobile

Comment: Strangelly that code worked with swiping in the browser but not in mobile

Comment: what did you use to test?

Comment: Chrome Developer Tools and my Moto X Style