# jQuery bind drag up and down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<div>` that is a full viewport container, inside the container I have some other divs that I move up or down based on user mousewheel scroll, even if the page never move because it doesn't scroll.

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel', function(e){
   // animate my objects inside viewport
});
```

on mobile phones and tablet I need to intercept user drag, even if is not really dragging anything, is most like a gesture UP or DOWN

How can I do it?

Comment: You might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/a/21644139/6080889

Comment: it seems is only possible with an external plugin