# how to swipe up and swipe down in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Can you please tell me how how to swipe up and swipe down in jQuery + jQuery mobile.

I already use this plugin:
[How to swipe top down JQuery mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131815/how-to-swipe-top-down-jquery-mobile)

Demerit: When I scroll the contents it calls swipe up and down function.
Can you please give best solution so that I will able to scroll my content and swipe up and down using jQuery or jQuery mobile.

Comment: I am using in ios and android TouchSwipe  >> http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/Handlers_and_events.html

Answer (score 9):

Download from https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin

Add in your html page

```
<script src="js/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>

$("#id").swipe( {
  swipeUp:function(event, direction, distance, duration) {
    //console.log("You swiped " + direction)
  },
  swipeDown:function(event, direction, distance, duration) {
    //console.log("You swiped " + direction) 
  },
  click:function(event, target) { 
  },
  threshold:100,
  allowPageScroll:"vertical"
});
```

OR try this one https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview