# Handling swipe up/down events in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery.touchSwipe.js in fiddle. I downloaded it from [here](https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin) and inserted jquery.touchSwipe.js in my dropbox .run, but it didn't work for. I want to capture swipe up and down events along with scrolling. Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/YB5sq/).

```
$("#test").swipe({
    swipeUp: function (event, direction, distance, duration) {
        console.log("You swiped " + direction)
    },
    swipeDown: function (event, direction, distance, duration) {
        console.log("You swiped " + direction)
    },
    click: function (event, target) {},
    threshold: 100,
    allowPageScroll: "vertical"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your path to the TouchSwipe plugin is incorrect. You are linking to Dropbox's download page rather than the file itself which is here:

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/asv82fbz1am8e8w/jquery.touchSwipe.js
```

I've updated your Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YB5sq/1/

**Update:**
From our discussion I *think* you also want to be able to *not* trigger a swipe event when the user is trying to scroll an element. You can do that to - the [documentation](http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/Excluded_children.html) tells you how. By default anything with a class of `noSwipe` won't trigger a swipe but you can also specify elements. E.G: http://jsfiddle.net/YB5sq/5/

Comment: But I am not getting swipe up and down event ..?

Comment: I am. Have you looked in the console to see if your logs are showing?

Comment: How to get swipe up and swipe down event .But I need user also scroll the contend.Actualy When I scroll contend it also fire the swipe and swipe down event

Comment: I am not getting any log

Comment: I try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131815/how-to-swipe-top-down-jquery-mobile but I am getting swipe up and down event when I scroll my contend

Comment: This fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/YB5sq/2/) gives an alert message when the swipe is detected.

Comment: That why I am using this library

Comment: Its works doesn't it? It detects the swipe now. What you choose to do with that info is up to you. You don't need touchSwipe for users on a touch-device to be able to scroll an element. That behaviour is built in. You use touchSwipe to enable things like swiping through slideshows or pages.

Comment: Actually my problem is that I have contend in a div Example page

Comment: In page there is a scrolling contend .now if user swipe up or swipe down it display the previous or next page.But when i am doing that when I am scrolling current page it dedect swipe up and down event and open previous or next page

Comment: can we reduce this div height so that style="scroll:auto;height:200px so that we can check all issues

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40874/discussion-between-user2648752-and-moob)