# Swipe up for Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, swipe

I am trying to do swipe up function for my web app.

I refered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131815/how-to-swipe-top-down-jquery-mobile). Using this I am getting the following problem.

1. In chrome android 4.4.2 - scroll is not working. Instead swipe is triggering every time.
2. IE 10 -  event itself not getting triggered.

Comment: Could you please check from this, might be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131815/how-to-swipe-top-down-jquery-mobile?lq=1

Comment: When you use swipe UP/DOWN function don't bind the function to the whole Page, just have the function for the elements you want to swipe up/down only. Another way is to stop the propagation of scroll to any other functions that may be affected. eg ($(document).on( 'scroll', '#listviewID', function(event){
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
});) As for IE10, youre bound to get all sorts of issues with this 2nd hand browser.