# Swipe up and down for Revolution Slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, revolution-slider

I am using Revolution Slider for a WordPress site - I need be able to vertically swipe through the slides in the slider. Currently, only horizontal swiping works. I was able to get the slider to respond to vertical mouse scrolls with the provided API but vertical swiping is not working.

I'm using this for the mouse scrolls and it's working fine:

```
(function() {

    // change "revapi1" here to whatever API name your slider uses (see notes below)
    var slider = revapi2;

    slider.parent().on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {

        if(event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) {

            slider.revprev();

        }
        else {

            slider.revnext();

        }

    });
```

**RE Vertica Swiping I found some code here**: [How to swipe top down JQuery mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131815/how-to-swipe-top-down-jquery-mobile)

but I'm not sure where to go from there or if it's even what I'm looking for.
so far i have:

swipe down for next slide:

```
(function() {
    var slider = revapi2;

slider.parent().on('swipedown', function(event) {
slider.revnext();
});

})()
```

swipe up for previous slide:

```
(function() {
    var slider = revapi2;

slider.parent().on('swipeup', function(event) {
slider.revprev();
});

})()
```

nothing is working - I'm pretty new to this stuff, so if you can point out where I'm going wrong too, that would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Very simple, actually. I just edited the plugins Js files found here:

revslider\rs-plugin\js

jquery.themepunch.revolution.min

and

jquery.themepunch.revolution

I found the "swipe functions" and replaced "left" with "up" and "right" with "down"

```
////////////////////////////
        // SET THE SWIPE FUNCTION //
        ////////////////////////////
        var swipeAction = function(container,opt) {
            // TOUCH ENABLED SCROLL
                var aps = "vertical";

                if (opt.touchenabled=="on") {
                            if (opt.drag_block_vertical == true) 
                                aps = "none";

                            container.swipe({

                                fingers:opt.swipe_min_touches,                              
                                treshold:opt.swipe_treshold,                                
                                swipe:function(event,direction,distance,duration,fingerCount,fingerData) {
                                    switch (direction) {
                                        case "up":
                                             if (opt.transition==0) {
                                                                opt.next = opt.next+1;
                                                                if (opt.next == opt.slideamount) opt.next=0;
                                                                callingNewSlide(opt,container);
                                                        }
                                        break;
                                        case "down":
                                            if (opt.transition==0) {
                                                                opt.next = opt.next-1;
                                                                opt.downarrowpressed=1;
                                                                if (opt.next < 0) opt.next=opt.slideamount-1;
                                                                callingNewSlide(opt,container);
```

Works like a dream!

Answer (score 0):

perfect solution! I would recommend to contact us also via http://themepunch.com/support-center and ask for an "out of box" solution, so you can keep your version always up to date with the latest version, and have the option available without the needs to add this change in the script directly every time you update.