# Jquery - recognise Swipe Up and Down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, swipe

I am using the jQuery function from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131815/how-to-swipe-top-down-jquery-mobile) in order to recognise 'swipe down' and 'swipe up' events.

The function is working fine if I use just swipedown or up however, I cannot find out how to recognise both direction inside one function. For example:

```
$("body").on("swipeupdown",function(){

  if (swipeUp == true) {

  alert("SwipedUp");
  }

if (swipeDown == true) {

  alert("SwipedDown");
  }

});
```

Any Idea how to implement this?

I have also tried the code below it works however, it counts the swipes and shows a lot of alert windows overtime i swipe.

```
$("body").on("swipeupdown",function(){


  $("body").on("swipedown",function(){

  alert("down");

  });

  $("body").on("swipeup",function(){

  alert("up");

  });


});
```

Comment: Would suggest checking out the JQuery Mobile framework. This adds virtual events for swiping.

Comment: Also, where is `swipeUp` and `swipeDown` defined?

Comment: Hi Twisty, they are not defined it was just an example of what I was trying to achieve. Please see my edit

Answer (score 1):

So you can catch more info about the event using this:

```
$(function(){
// Bind the swipeHandler callback function to the swipe event
    $( "body" ).on( "swipe", swipeHandler );

    // Callback function references the event target and adds the 'swipe' class to it
    function swipeHandler( event ){
       console.log( event );
    }
});
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/be5z0vko/

This will give you a object and you can find ways to determine which direction the swipe was. For example, the `event.swipestart` and `event.swipestop` contain `coords`, so you can use those to determine the direction.

Also look here: http://developingwithstyle.blogspot.com/2010/11/jquery-mobile-swipe-up-down-left-right.html In-depth but would be much more precise if you need it.